# Chromium - right click menus and system bar button do not render

Tags: gnome, snap, chromium, gtk, 21.10

I had been using Ubuntu 21.04 (GNOME) till now but a few days back when I upgraded to 21.10 I started getting these wierd error messages from chromium when launched from the terminal. I tried to ignore it but then this started happening within the application:

[image: Right click menu appears as a green-white box with random colored dots - like the static in old CRT TVs]

The green-black box appears whenever I right click on a link. Right clicks on plaintext or system title bars work fine but when I do on links (for example to open a new tab) it wont load properly. This also happens in drop-down menus when filling online forms - though if you know what sequence the options are placed in you can guess and select the right option. This means that the menu works, and I can interact with it, just that it doesn't render properly.

Also notice in the screenshot that the close/maximize/minimize/buttons don't show up in the title bar. They too, don't render but still can be interacted with (clicking on red circle still closes the app, clicking slightly left of it still maximises the app).

Terminal output:

```
user@hostname:~$ chromium
/home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so
/home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so
/home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so

(chrome:3786): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:16:43.755: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1418:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(chrome:3786): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:16:43.764: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3295:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(chrome:3786): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:16:43.767: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3757:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
GLib-GIO-Message: 12:16:44.395: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(chrome:3786): dbind-WARNING **: 12:16:48.871: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-HZ2HAPt7gP: No such file or directory
[4047:4047:1207/121650.873694:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

(chrome:3786): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:16:51.024: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.024: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.024: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.026: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.026: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.027: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.027: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.715: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.715: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.716: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.716: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.717: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:51.717: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:54.495: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:54.495: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121654.495619:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121654.495645:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:54.496: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:54.496: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121654.496816:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121654.496834:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:54.497: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:54.497: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121654.497690:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121654.497707:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
[3786:3906:1207/121658.508197:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(98)] Failed to begin udev enumeration.

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:59.102: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:16:59.102: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121659.103178:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121659.103218:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
[3786:4075:1207/121659.995153:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[3786:4075:1207/121659.995210:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[3786:4075:1207/121659.995236:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[3786:4075:1207/121700.105437:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.155: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.155: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.157: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.157: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.158: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.158: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.249: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.249: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.250: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.250: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.251: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.251: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.302: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.302: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.304: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.304: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.306: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.306: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.316: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.316: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121701.316495:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121701.316525:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.318: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.318: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121701.318658:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121701.318682:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.320: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.320: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121701.320938:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gdk: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
[3786:3786:1207/121701.320966:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(269)] Gtk: gtk_css_style_render_icon_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed

(chrome:3786): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 12:17:01.336: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
```

The last few lines repeat more for about 20 times and more error messages appear the more I try to use chromium.

---

I tried `snap revert chromium` but it doesn't make a difference.

Did `snap refresh` and the problem still persists.

---

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810888/right-click-shows-black-box-in-chrome-on-linux) I tried disabling hardware acceleration in chromium settings and the **right click menus are fixed**. I don't see significant performance loss so maybe I can leave it that way. However, the **system title bar icons still don't show up**.

Is this an issue with chromium itself? Or have I broken my installation somewhow? I have not installed any custom themes - I use the default Yaru theme with dark mode (from Ubuntu settings.)

Also, not sure if this is related but pages within chromium never seem to respect the dark mode settings on my system. For example, if I open github.com on firefox, it opens in dark theme, but when I open it in chromium, it opens in the default white theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind they fixed it in an update. Right click menus and system title bar behave as expected (even with hardware acceleration turned on).

Edit - Problem had persisted over a number of updates. Snaps update without your consent so I can't really tell how many, but it had been there for about a week when I posted the question. Anyway it's fixed now in snap version 97.0.4692.99